# EaselJS : Bitmap Animation : Setting Frame Speed

Tags: performance, bitmap, frame, easeljs, createjs

How is it possible to set the FRAME SPEED for an individual Bitmap Animation if I need it to run say at 10% the application FPS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frequency of the animation in the spritesheet's constructor.

For Example:

```
 animations: {
        // start, end, next, frequency
        jump: [9,12,"run",2]
    }
```

or

```
 animations: {
        jump: {
            frames: [8,9,10,9,8],
            next: "run",
            frequency: 2
        }
    }
```

By default it's 1, so if you put 10 it will be 10 times slower.